# How to wrap a Backbone view element with a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am facing issues in adding wrapper div on strut Slidesnapshot which uses Backbone.js.

```
render: function() {
    if (this._slideDrawer) {
        this._slideDrawer.dispose();
    }
    this.$el.addClass('testall');
    this.$el.wrap('<div class="check"></div>');
    this.$el.html(this._template(this.model.attributes));
```

`.addClass` added the class on div but I am not able to wrap the html inside parent div.

Answer (score 0):

A Backbone view represents one DOM element, which is accessible with [`view.el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el).

Often, a parent view is rendering the child view before putting its element in the DOM. So the child view wraps itself with a `div`, but then the parent still uses `view.el` to get the original element.

Though **I strongly suggest rethinking the need to wrap a child div**, here's a way to accomplish it with Backbone:

```js
var Child = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: "<span>This is the template</span>",
  render: function() {
    // create a wrapper
    var $wrap = $('<div class="check"></div>');
    // keep a reference to the original element
    this.$innerEl = (this.$innerEl || this.$el).addClass('testall')
      .html(this.template);
    // wrap the inner element.
    $wrap.html(this.$innerEl);

    // then replace the view el.
    this.setElement($wrap);
    return this;
  }
});

var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#app',
  initialize: function() {
    this.child = new Child();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.child.render().el);
    return this;
  }
});

var parent = new Parent();
parent.render();
parent.render(); // make sure it's idempotent
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

*Inspect the result with dev tools to see the wrapping `div`.*

Answer (score 0):

The right way to go about this would be to customize the view element as your wrapper, and adding a child `<div>` with required classes (current view element) to the template if required. For example:

```js
var V = new Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'check',
  render: function(){}
});
```

This will result in the same DOM structure. You can customize the view element as you wish using [View-attributes](http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes). This will keep the code more maintainable and less prone to bugs in future. I don't see a reason to hack around.